# Force iCloud Music Library to update based on info in my Mac iTunes Library?

Tags: itunes, icloud, music, library

Something went wrong with my iCloud Music Library this morning.  I now have a few thousand songs with incorrect metadata.

I have a backup of my Mac's iTunes Music Library, and the backup is correct.  When I restore the backup, my library is correct again for a few minutes, until iCloud Music Library syncs and replaces the correct metadata with its incorrect metadata, presumably because iCML sees that its own info is more recent than my backup.  ARGH!

NOTES:

The only library I care about is my Mac's iTunes library.  I use iCloud Music Library for Apple Music downloads on my Mac, but I've turned it off on all of my other devices (an iPhone and an iPad).  I've also deleted all music from my iPhone and iPad in order to make it easier to fix this problem.

How do I force iCloud Music Library to sync its metadata with the correct info in my Mac iTunes Library?

Comment: If the "more recent info" suggestion is really the problem, you could try to (1) disconnect from the internet (2) restore you backup (3) update metadata for all songs (e.g. select all, add a comment, save, then delete the comment) (4) reconnect and see what happens. However, I had similar problems before (only for single songs, though) and I think the meta-data update isn't very reliable - it always stupidly tends to prefer the online info.

Comment: THANK YOU!  Geez, your solution is obvious, and I mean that in the best possible sense, as it should accomplish exactly what I want.  And yet, it hadn't occurred to me.  If it doesn't work, then it shows the problem is bigger than I thought - though, it shouldn't work since it looks like my backup is correct and iCML is wrong.

Comment: Shoot!  iCloud Music Library is doing crazy things.  I added the word "UPDATED" to the comments for every single song.  Then I quit iTunes and backed up my iTunes library files.  As soon as I turned on wifi again, iCloud Music Library started deleting ratings and sometimes also deleting the UPDATED comment.  I can't fathom what's going on here.

Comment: Could you completely turn off iCloud Music Library and then re-enable (and re-upload) everything?

Comment: Turning off iCloud Music Library doesn't delete its contents.  I've done that before, while trying to solve problems with iCML.  The only solution I've found that works is to only use iCML on one device (my Mac).  As soon as a second device gets added, iCML seems to lose track of which files are more recent.  Inevitably, iCML prioritizes its metadata in the cloud over the metadata in my iTunes library, even when iTunes is more current.  I'll change ratings, loves, etc, on songs in iTunes, iCML changes the info back or deletes it.  It's maddening.  Delete songs?  iCML re-adds them.

Comment: I guess they are pretty worried about deleting your files - nobody wants to accidentally delete songs in your Library - I certainly agree that it's nowhere near as good as Dropbox sync, but I thought there was an option to remove songs from iCloud Music Library through iTunes - are you saying there is no way to remove any songs ?

Comment: I'm saying that, often, when you remove songs from iCML, they are no longer shown, but often reappear after a few minutes or perhaps hours.  This suggests that deleting them doesn't really delete them.  And let's be honest here.  iCML probably doesn't store music.  It's probably a database since there's no reason to store the same song thousands of times for different people on the same iCML server.  I'm saying, the database is deeply flawed.  Sometimes, deleting is only temporary.  Often, the iCML database seems to get confused.

Comment: Did anyone ever find a solution to this? Absolutely all of my Apple Music songs are just gone right now and I can’t get a backup restore to work because iCloud Music Library just keeps deleting them again

Comment: Alex, I had to contact Apple Support and have them reset my entire iCloud Music Library.  It was a giant pain, but nothing else worked.  Sorry I don't have better news.  You're going to have to contact Apple tech support.

Comment: Thanks @2oh1, I ended up calling Apple on Tuesday and of course they escalated it 9,000,000 times and couldn't figure it out, then handed it off to engineering. They claim they're calling me back this morning, but it's least promising that there may be a way to recover it

Comment: They told me "icloud music library cannot be reset and nor can you overwrite it with a local copy, you're out of luck and have to add all 900 songs back manually". What support channel did you through? I'm just at a total loss here @2oh1

Comment: I contacted Apple Music support on Twitter, but I probably just got lucky by getting a reply.  The reply led to a series of exchanges that eventually led to being contacted on the phone by an Apple tech who was able to document the issue enough to get my iCloud Music Library reset.  If I were you, I'd find a way to record your screen to document the issue as it happens, and I'd try contacting Apple support and sending them that video.  In my case, you could literally watch as iTunes songs were deleting metadata by themselves.  GOOD LUCK!