# How can I recover an iTunes backup with iCloud Music Library enabled?

Tags: itunes, icloud, backup, music

Long story, but my iTunes library got totally ruined. All of my older manually added and purchased songs are fine, but my Apple Music songs (so basically all of my music from the last 5 years) is just gone. I have a backup from last night at 5:00pm right before this happened, however I cannot recover it. I replaced my entire iTunes directory including the `.itl` and `.xml` library files with the backup, but the iCloud library instantly deletes all of my Apple Music songs again. The library itself works perfectly ok with the network cable unplugged, as expected. Instant I plug it back in, the deletion fest begins.

I think I just need to force overwrite the iCloud Music Library with my local library, but I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: Could be similar to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245651/force-icloud-music-library-to-update-based-on-info-in-my-mac-itunes-library but no solution was found